# how to read and get the values from xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

how to read and get the values of "name","age" and "sex" using c#?

```
<Details>
    <Name>xx</Name>
    <age>yy</age>
    <sex>zz</sex>
</Details>
```

Comment: You need to do a little bit of research on your own. A simple search on this website or Google will give you loads of results with examples of "parsing XML in C#".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\testapp\sample.xml");
// Root element
System.Xml.XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
System.Xml.XmlElement nameElement =(System.Xml.XmlElement)root.ChildNodes[0];
string name = name.InnerText;
System.Xml.XmlElement ageElemnent =(System.Xml.XmlElement)root.ChildNodes[1];
string age = ageElemnent.InnerText;
System.Xml.XmlElement sexElemnent =(System.Xml.XmlElement)root.ChildNodes[2];
string sex= sexElemnent.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx):

```
  var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
  var list = xdoc.Root.Descendants().Select(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for xml parsers,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `XmlDocument` out of your xml. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)
2. Fire `XPath` query over that document using [XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode.aspx) method.
3. Get the `InnerText` of result form #2 above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

            string myXml=@"<Details>
                        <Name>xx</Name>
                        <age>yy</age>
                        <sex>zz</sex>
                        </Details>";
            xml.LoadXml(myXml);


            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Details");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                string name = xn["Name"].InnerText;
                string age = xn["age"].InnerText;
                string text = xn["sex"].InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1} {2}", name, age, text);
            }
```

***You should get some information before asking this***

Answer (score 0):

Also LINq to XML:

```
        XElement x = XElement.Load("In.xml");
        var details = new
        {
            Name = x.Element("Name").Value,
            Age = x.Element("age").Value,
            Sex = x.Element("sex").Value
        };
```

and use it then, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(details.Name);
Console.WriteLine(details.Age);
Console.WriteLine(details.Sex);
```